Finding proper expressions for DistributionLambda parameters in TensorFlow Probability
In TensorFlow Probability, when we build a model with DistributionLambda layer, we must pass the expressions for distribution parameters. Most often, these expressions  transform the output of previos layer in some way.
For example, in tutorial:
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1 + 1),
    tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(
        lambda t: tfd.Normal(loc=t[..., :1],
                             scale=1e-3 + tf.math.softplus(0.05 * t[...,1:]))),])

we got an expression for scale parameter.
Also in the same example we got:
scale=1e-5 + tf.nn.softplus(c + t[..., n:])),

I couldn't find any mention of what methodology was used to find these expressions.
Is there a procedure for finding expressions for the parameters of a distribution (something like the maximum likelihood estimation, for example)?
